# Querying multiple tables from 1 API with different names, but same structure in nestjs TypeORM

Tags: sql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a question regarding TypeORM queries. I am designing an app and the database was already existing. It is written poorly and is decent size and the customer doesn't want it changed. The problem is, each object (let's call it a supermarket) has it's own table in the database.
For example:
Supermarket New York ==> supermarket_ny_1
Supermarket Paris ==> supermarket_par_1

Tables have the exact same data types with exact same names, but the name of table is different. Currently, as i'm a nest beginner, i created an entity called supermarket_ny_1 and now when i'm writing the API for it, it's apparent that when making queries in a service and injecting repositories, it needs to work for all the supermarkets. I thought i could make a parent class for my entity that would contain all the neccessary columns, but when making a query i still need the exact name for the database

Comment: Could you please clearly mention what are your expectations with some data examples? Showing some demo table data?

Comment: Ok let's say there is a  table supermarket_ny_1. It has columns of: 
-ID
-LocationId (FK)
-Name
If i query this specific table, i just inject a repository with <table-name> type, and it's solved. But how would i make it generic for all the supermarkets. Here is the example from my code for login: 
`
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(login) private usersRepository: Repository<login>
      ){}
`
Here i specify <login> repository, which is the actual name in my database, what if i don't know the actual table name before a made request

Comment: It's better to edit the question itself with appropriate code formatting. I believe you are talking about fetching data from multi-tenant-based schemas, right?